# Create model instance twice from one form

Tags: python, django

I have a page that displays a lesson, which includes a `DateTime`. The lesson model also has an attribute called `lesson_weekly`, that is a checkbox that a user selects if they want to repeat the object every week. For example, if the date is set as `2019-01-01 10:00 am`, and `lesson_weekly` is checked, I want the `lesson` object to be duplicated and displayed, but with +7 to the date, so the date would be `2019-01-08 10:00` am. I believe this can be done by simply adding 7 days to this date, but am unsure how to do it so that it works properly and the date switches to the next month if it passes the last date such as the 30th or 31st. I would appreciate any suggestions in how to do this.

**models.py**

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=None, related_name='lessons', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson_instrument = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=instrument_list, blank=True)
    lesson_level = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=level_list, blank=True)
    lesson_length = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=length_list, blank=True)
    lesson_datetime_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    lesson_weekly = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lessons

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_lessons(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Lesson.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_lessons(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        for lesson in instance.lessons.all():
            lesson.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class LessonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lesson_instrument = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_length = forms.ChoiceField(choices=length_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_datetime_start = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute am/pm'}))
    lesson_weekly = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('lesson_instrument', 'lesson_level', 'lesson_length', 'lesson_datetime_start', 'lesson_weekly')
```

**views.py**

```
def profile(request, user_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.time_zone:
        activate(request.user.time_zone)
    else:
        deactivate()

    lessons = Lesson.objects.filter(user=user_id).order_by('lesson_datetime_start')
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    form = TeacherProfileForm()
    context = {'form' : form, 'user' : user, 'lessons' : lessons}
    return render(request, 'view/profile.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            {% for lesson in lessons %}
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">{{ lesson.lesson_instrument }}</td>
                <td>{{ lesson.lesson_level }}</td>
                <td>{{ lesson.lesson_length }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% load tz %}
                    {% timezone user.time_zone %}
                    {{ lesson.lesson_datetime_start|date}}
                    {% endtimezone %}
                </td>
                <td>{{ lesson.lesson_datetime_start|time}}</td>
                <td>$30</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn blue_button">Book now</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How many times do you want to duplicate the object? Just once? Or recurring indefinitely every week? Do you really want to save multiple objects in the database or would you be happy to just display each occurrence in the table?

Comment: @Asher Displaying it would be fine, how would that process occur?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to duplicate the lesson object, you want to generate the dates for a lesson keeping in mind the frequency for the lesson chosen by the user.
Given this, I would model this a bit differently as below, giving you more flexibility and scalability with your lesson model and different lesson times.

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
   FREQUENCY_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('DAILY', 'DAILY'),
    ('WEEKLY', 'WEEKLY'),
    ('MONTHLY', 'MONTHLY'),
)

   user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=None, 
          related_name='lessons', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   lesson_instrument = models.CharField(max_length=255, 
          choices=instrument_list, blank=True)
   lesson_level = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=level_list, 
            blank=True)
   lesson_length = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=length_list, 
          blank=True)
   lesson_datetime_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   lesson_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
                      choices=FREQUENCY_TYPE_CHOICES)


class LessonTime(models.Model):
     lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, related_name='lesson_times')
     lesson_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

In your template, when the user chooses a frequency option and enters a start-date, you can then auto generate the future dates and link these to the lesson instance. On submitting the form, both the lesson and its corresponding lesson-dates are saved.

**generate dates based on a start_date, end_date**

```
## your start_date, end_date should be a datetime object
def generate_lesson_dates(start, end, step):
    lesson_dates = []
    current = start
    while current < end:
       lesson_dates.append(current)
       current += step

generate_lesson_dates(start_date, end_date, datetime.timedelta(days=7))]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. One quick question, how would I go about generating the future dates?